# exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot make the link absolute

Tags: java, url

The task of this homework is to extract all valid links from a webpage by using regular expressions..So far this is what i've written, but when i compile it,this is the output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException ..ecc
Could you tell me what should I modify in order to make the code work? (Sorry if the question is not clear, but i dont have so much experience in programming..)

public class LinkGetter {

```
private Pattern html;
private Pattern link;

public LinkGetter() {

    html = Pattern.compile("<a\\b[^>]*href=\"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>");
    link = Pattern.compile("href=\"[^>]*\">");
}

public List<String> getLinks(String url) {

    List<String> links = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }

        Matcher tagmatch = html.matcher(builder.toString());
        while (tagmatch.find()) {
            Matcher matcher = link.matcher(tagmatch.group());
            matcher.find();
            String link = matcher.group().replaceFirst(" ", "")
                    .replaceFirst("\">", "")
                    .replaceFirst("\"[\\s]?target=\"[a-zA-Z_0-9]*", "");
            if (valid(link)) {
                links.add( Integer.parseInt( url ),link);
            }
          }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
            return links;
}

private boolean valid(String line) {
    if (line.matches("javascript:.*|mailto:.*")) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private String makeAbsolute(String url, String link) throws RuntimeException {
    if (link.matches("http://.*")) {
        return link;
    }
    if (link.matches("/.*") && url.matches(".*$[^/]")) {
        return url + "/" + link;
    }
    if (link.matches("[^/].*") && url.matches(".*[^/]")) {
        return url + "/" + link;
    }
    if (link.matches("/.*") && url.matches(".*[/]")) {
        return url + link;
    }
    if (link.matches("/.*") && url.matches(".*[^/]")) {
        return url + link;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot make the link absolute. Url: " + url
                               + " Link " + link);
}

public static void main(String []args){

    LinkGetter linkGetter = new LinkGetter();
    List<String> links = linkGetter.getLinks( url );

}
```

Comment: I guess it's not happening during compile time as there's a thread main so I guess it's happening during runtime. The full stacktrace may help. It's not clear as well what you're asking for. A wild guess is that you're feeding an HTML line with anchor tag that is not parsed correctly by the regex. Can you please rephrase the question for the community to better help?

Comment: Weak title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am getting out of your code is you are trying to get all the links from **https://www.repubblica.it/** and trying to save it in your **links** list.

The error I am gettig while trying to execute your code straight forward

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "https://www.repubblica.it/"

Which is self evident because your are trying to parse url to Integer on line:

```
links.add( Integer.parseInt( url ),link);
```

Moment I changed it to below and it worked and fetched all the links on the page.

```
links.add(link);
```